# Software updater can't upgrade from 14.10 to 15.04

Tags: upgrade, 14.10, update-manager, 15.04

I want to upgrade my distro from version 14.10 to 15.04, for this I've used software updater utility to perform this upgrade. One or two days ago software updater could download some new packages but I stopped it to resume it later.

Today, when I launch software updater, it fails in phase `Setting new software channels`, here's error message:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivi/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
<!-- I've skipped simmilar lines -->
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What does it mean 404 Not Found? Have that packages been deleted in the server?

I am now using Iran server, could this problem be solved if I choose main server?

However if you hit [this address](http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid/universe/binary-amd64/Packages) by your brower, you would get 404 not found too.

Comment: It appears as though the server is down, you should try using the main server.

Comment: @Toroidal Seems the server is not down, please open [this link](http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid/universe/binary-amd64/). But this directory does not have a file named `Packages`

Comment: @Toroidal However I am now trying the main server. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open software and updates, choose Download from <kbd>Other</kbd> 
[image: best server]

Then click <kbd>Select Best Server</kbd> a series of tests will be performed to find the best mirror for your location. A server will be recommended. Choose it and try again.